# 2.8 - Non Linear Animation Editor - How to remove tracks?

Tags: animation

I was wondering, how can I get rid of unwanted/unnecessary tracks in the NLA Editor? (i.e. [Action Stash] & [Action Stash].001)
Rightclick -> Remove Empty Animation Data does not do the trick.

Thanks!

[image: NLA Editor]

Comment: you're probably talking about tracks, not strip, X seems to work

Comment: I fixed/edited it for future reference.. Thanks, and yes I meant tracks. X does indeed work! I could swear I tried it but nothing happens. Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Put your mouse on the track name and press <kbd>X</kbd>